# Getting "Object in use" error in C# code for image processing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, image, winforms

I'm working on a C# application where I'm performing image processing and encountering an issue with the "Object in use" error. Here's a simplified version of the code that's causing the problem:

```
private void piccc(object s)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
    {
        ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
        ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();
        foreach (Control c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
        {
            if (((Label)c.Controls[0]).Text == "   ")
            {
                string[] ll3 = ((PictureBox)c.Controls[1]).Name.Split(',');
                matrix.Matrix33 = (float)int.Parse(ll3[6]) / 100;
                attributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
                gfx.DrawImage((Bitmap)((PictureBox)c.Controls[1]).Image, new Rectangle(int.Parse(ll3[0]), int.Parse(ll3[1]), int.Parse(ll3[11]), int.Parse(ll3[12]), int.Parse(ll3[2]), int.Parse(ll3[3]), int.Parse(ll3[4]), int.Parse(ll3[5]), GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void pictureboxpaint()
{
    ParameterizedThreadStart param = new ParameterizedThreadStart(piccc);
    Thread thread = new Thread(param);
    thread.Start();
}
```

The issue arises when I try to draw images onto pictureBox1 using a separate thread. I suspect it's related to concurrent access to the graphics object, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Can someone please provide guidance on how to prevent the "Object in use" error and ensure proper thread safety in this code?

I'd appreciate any suggestions or explanations regarding the issue and how to rectify it. Thank you!

Edit: i'm getting this error at this line:
`gfx.DrawImage((Bitmap)((PictureBox)c.Controls[1]).Image, new Rectangle(int.Parse(ll3[0]), int.Parse(ll3[1]), int.Parse(ll3[11]), int.Parse(ll3[12]), int.Parse(ll3[2]), int.Parse(ll3[3]), int.Parse(ll3[4]), int.Parse(ll3[5]), GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);`

Comment: I think the resouce is in use and any other process will be denied.
1-if you are using multi thread try to lock and unlock for a resource.
2- I think in this problem you can define global variable for image and fill it,and then do any thing you want on that variable.

Comment: @Behtash if i lock them the speed goes even slower than normal thread and also i can't use global variables because i have infinit objects

Comment: My advice is that don't perform drawing code on other threads but the UI thread. If you have time consuming operations like resizing images etc, refactor your code so that you perform the computations on another thread and then execute the actual drawing code.

Comment: You cannot create, access, or update any UI element from a non-UI thread. Period.